# WP_Query Search is not working.....for keyword 'TATTOO'

Tags: wordpress

This search is not working.... Any guess?? This is a very simple piece of code.

It is for showing records related with keyword tattoo for title field. It shows all products. The search is not triggered.

```
$args = array(


                      'posts_per_page' => $per_page,
                      'offset'      =>  $paged,
                      'post_type'   => 'product',
                      'meta_key'    => $orderby,
                      'orderby'     => $num_orderby,
                      'order'       => $order,
                      'search'  =>  '*tattoo*',
                      'search_columns'  => array('post_title')
                );      

                    $new_query = new WP_Query( $args );`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter

try use 's' instead 'search'

```
  ...
  's'  =>  '*tattoo*',
  ...
```

Comment: What about the 'search_columns' ? I want to specify search on 'title' field.